# How to improve resolution of plot with underflow and overflow?

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I am working with a function that has the form

```
Exp[-a^2](Erfi[a]-Log[-1/a]-Log[a])/a
```

where `a` is complex number. When I tried to plot it, my expression yields underflow and overflow. Here, you can see that my blue plot is oscillating because of this problem. I want to make a nice and clean plot! `PlotPoints` will make it little better, but there still is a missing region. Any help?

[image: bad plot]

Here is a sample function (It might take a few seconds)

```
f[d_]:=(1/(2 Sqrt[(-2562890621 - 
    112500 I) π]))(-((2 - 28125 I) + 
      Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] + 4500 I Sqrt[70]) E^(-(1/
     16) ((-2 + 50629 I) + Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] - 
      4 d)^2) (π Erfi[
       1/4 ((-2 + 50629 I) + Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] - 4 d)] - 
     Log[(-2 + 50629 I) + Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] - 4 d] - 
     Log[1/((2 - 50629 I) - Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] + 
       4 d)]) + ((-2 + 28125 I) + Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] - 
     4500 I Sqrt[70]) E^(-(1/
     16) ((2 - 50629 I) + Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] + 
      4 d)^2) (π Erfi[
       1/4 ((2 - 50629 I) + Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] + 4 d)] + 
     Log[(-2 + 50629 I) - Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] - 4 d] + 
     Log[1/((2 - 50629 I) + Sqrt[-2562890621 - 112500 I] + 4 d)]))
Plot[Im[f[d]],{d,-10,10}]
```

or (Same thing, I just make it look nicer)

```
k = -2562890621-112500I;
l = 2-28125I;
o = 2-50629I;
kk[d_] :=
 1/(2 Sqrt[k Pi])*
(-(l+Sqrt[k]+4500 I Sqrt[70]) E^(-(1/16)(-o+Sqrt[k]-4d)^2)(Pi Erfi[1/4(-o+Sqrt[k]-4d)]-Log[-o+Sqrt[k]-4d]-Log[1/(o-Sqrt[k]+4d)])
   +(l+Sqrt[k]-4500 I Sqrt[70]) E^(-(1/16)(o+Sqrt[k]+4d)^2)(Pi Erfi[1/4(o+Sqrt[k]+4d)]+Log[-o-Sqrt[k]-4d]+Log[1/(o+Sqrt[k]+4d)]))
Plot[Im[kk[d]], {d, -10, 10}]
```

[image: still bad]

Comment: Evaluate these two values, `{Im[f[3.]],
Im[f[2.]]}` to see why some places have no line

Comment: @JasonB. I think those results are due to numerical errors; he is aware of that problem (hence his reference to underflow / overflow), and he is asking for a solution for it. Even increasing `WorkingPrecision` dramatically, however, does not seem to solve the problem. Saesun, I wonder if you can rewrite / Simplify / refactor your expression to a form that isn't affected by such huge errors.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to refactor my expression, I will let you know if it works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
With[{k = -2562890621 - 112500 I, l = 2 - 28125 I, o = 2 - 50629 I}, 
     Plot[With[{c = -l - 4500 Sqrt[-70], f = 2 Sqrt[π],
                sm = -o + Sqrt[k] - 4 d, sp = o + Sqrt[k] + 4 d}, 
               Im[((c - Sqrt[k]) (f DawsonF[sm/4] - 
                   Exp[-(sm/4)^2] (Log[sm] + Log[-1/sm])) +
                   (c + Sqrt[k]) (f DawsonF[sp/4] + 
                   Exp[-(sp/4)^2] (Log[-sp] + Log[1/sp])))/(f Sqrt[k])]],
          {d, -10, 10}]]
```

[image: plot]

---

## Notes

1. Be kind to yourself; identify common subexpressions and isolate them. You'll thank yourself later when you're debugging.
2. In applications, the imaginary error function $\operatorname{erfi}(z)$ is not the quantity of interest, but rather its exponentially-scaled version, [Dawson's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html) (built-in as `DawsonF[]`). This has the advantage of being bounded even for large values.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me Dawson's integral!

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a continuous `Plot`, you can interpolate the available  `Plot` data.

```
plot1 = Plot[Im[f[d]], {d, -10, 10}];

points = Join @@ Cases[plot1, Line[pts__] :> pts, Infinity];

f2 = Interpolation[points];

{min, max} = MinMax[points[[All, 1]]];

Plot[f2[d], {d, min, max}]
```

[image]